# LNK2038 error VC++ 2013

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm currently trying to get a TMX-Parser hooked into my game, and after doing the appropriate hooking into, I get the following linker errors:

`Error  1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in base64.obj    tinyxml.lib(tinyxml.obj)`

`Error  5   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in base64.obj   tinyxml.lib(tinyxmlparser.obj)`

`Error  7   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in base64.obj   tinyxml.lib(tinyxmlerror.obj)`

`Error  4   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in base64.obj tinyxml.lib(tinyxml.obj)`

`Error  6   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in base64.obj tinyxml.lib(tinyxmlparser.obj)`

`Error  8   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in base64.obj tinyxml.lib(tinyxmlerror.obj)`

I've done some searching and can't figure out how to fix these, if anyone could give me some assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the errors:
MDd_DynamicDebug -> MDd **Multi-Theaded DLL Debug**
MD_DynamicDebug  -> MD  **Multi-Theaded DLL Release**

Your project and the library are compiled with different configuration (some types have distinct memory layout in debug and release, for debug checks and other tricks).

Other problem is the value of macro **_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL** in one compilation is **0** and in the other is **2** (one without debugging checks in debug other with, probably release is without and debug is with the check). This is related with the previous problem (types with members for checks in debug), trying to be used as the member do'nt exists.

Comment: Is it not required of a .lib to be compiled in release mode? This is how I've done my `SDL.lib` and I've yet to get an error from that.

Comment: more info about the project would be helpful, like if the project and the library share code, the settings of compilation of both. It appear that you have the same code compiled in base64 and tinyxmlerror compilation unit and the linker is trying to match the functions (one in debug and one in release config).

Comment: Well the thing about it is `tinyxml` is a library widely available, that another file I'm trying to use - `TMXLoader.h` and `.cpp` - uses as well, and also uses `base64`. I've now tried doing a debug and release version of `tinyxml` and the errors remain the same.

Comment: The problem is not tinyxml, [same problem here](http://www.d3dcoder.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=490). The problem is not compile a debug and release version is use this in linking. If you could manage a reduced sample code, with the problem i would take a look.